# Resolvent of a operator with variable coefficients $x^2\partial_{x}^2$

Tags: operator-theory

I am studying the resolvent of operators and the following question has arisen:

In $\mathbb{R}$, for the Laplacian operator $\partial_{x}^2$, it is natural that the resolvent operator is $R_{\lambda}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((\lambda+\xi^2)^{-1}\widehat{f}(\xi))(x)$  since $L_{\lambda}:=(\lambda-\partial_{x}^2)f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((\lambda+\xi^2)\widehat{f}(\xi))(x)$ and
$$L_{\lambda}\circ R_{\lambda}=Id,\quad R_{\lambda}\circ L_{\lambda}=Id$$
Given the above. What would be the resolving operator for the operator $x^2\partial_ {x}^2$?

In this case, the factor $x^2$ complicates things since
\begin{align}(\lambda-x^2\partial_{x}^2)f(x)&=\int e^{ix\xi}(\lambda+x^2\xi^2)\widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi\\
&=\int e^{ix\xi}\lambda \widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi+\int e^{ix\xi}x^2\xi^2\widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi\\
&=\lambda f(x)+x^2\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi^2\widehat{f}(\xi))(x)
\end{align}
and I don't know what else could be done to find the resolving operator.
Do you know any text where these examples are seen?

Comment: The Fourier transform isn't great with non-constant coefficients. However, note that $- x^{2} e^{i \xi x} = \partial_{\xi}^{2} (e^{i \xi x})$ and then integrate by parts. You'll need some regularity assumptions on $f$ (that it is a [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) I think) but if you include that then everything works out I think.